# Is there a way to set a var in PhpStorm Template thanks a config file?

Tags: phpstorm, apache-velocity

In PhpStorm, I´m doing this php file template using Apache velocity:

**Php template**

```
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

use function $plugin_name_namespace\Core\get_current_plugin_domain;

printf( '<article class="post-entry-content">' );
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    printf( '<a class="post-thumbnail-link" href="%s">%s</a>',
        get_the_permalink(),
        get_the_post_thumbnail()
    );
}
echo '<div class="post-content">';
printf( '<h4 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" title="%s" rel="bookmark">%s</a></h4>',
    get_the_permalink(),
    get_the_title(),
    get_the_title()
);
printf( '<div class="entry-excerpt">%s</div>' ,get_the_excerpt() );
printf('<a href="%s" class="details-link button" rel="nofollow">%s</a>',
    get_the_permalink(),
    __( "See More", get_current_plugin_domain() )
);
echo '</div>';
echo '</article>';

?>
```

I would like with apache velocity to set `$plugin_name_namespace` up with a defalut value from a config file ( .ini, .env ... whatever )

or..

to dynamicaly fill the template up with the value from the config file.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Not really (I do not know about such functionality and built-in does not allow it). But you may try [File Template Variables plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7398-file-template-variables) that can provide default values for such variables. Used to work in the past (have not used this plugin for maybe 3 years now so not sure if it still works). You can check for other possible plugins [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?correctionAllowed=false&orderBy=relevance&pr=phpstorm&search=template&pr_productId=phpstorm).

Comment: @LazyOne, I tried the plugin, the only thing it seems to do is exactly if I write `#set my_var = "a value"`

Comment: Pretty much, but that value comes from an IDE config (I believe t can be configured on per project level) and not hardcoded into the template itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently possible, please vote for [IDEA-217553](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217553) to be notified on any progress with this feature